# Best way to transferall stocks function

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am trying to make my transfer check my transactions.

If Buyer price is priced higher than sale price, sell to buyer at sale price.

What do i need to do to Sell it all accordingly?

if Sellers:

```
{amount:300,price: 2, firmid: 2}
{amount:200,price: 5, firmid: 2},
```

Buyers:

```
{amount: 400, price: 6, firmid: 2},
```

then i will buy all 300 stocks for 2, and 100 out of the 200 for 5,
What would be best way to approach this, for all the buyers for their price compared to sellers?

Calling CheckTransfers with any firmid.

```
function CheckTransfers(firmid) {
    return GetBuyersForStock(firmid).then(function (Buyers) {
        return GetSellersForStock(firmid).then(function (Sellers) {
            var NumSeller = 0;
            Buyers.forEach(BuyersData => {

                if (BuyersData.price >= Sellers[NumSeller].price) {
                    // BUY AT SALEPRICE
                    var NumStocks = (BuyersData.amount <= Sellers[NumSeller].amount ? BuyersData.amount : Sellers[NumSeller.amount]);
                    console.log("BUYING " + NumStocks + " for " + Sellers[NumSeller].price);


                }
            });
        });
    });
}

function GetSellersForStock(firmid) {
    return StockTransferPlatform.find({type: 'seller', firmid: firmid, completed: false, withdraw: false}).then(function (sellers) {
        return sellers;
    });
}
function GetBuyersForStock(firmid) {
    return StockTransferPlatform.find({type: 'buyer', firmid: firmid, completed: false, withdraw: false}).then(function (sellers) {
        return sellers;
    });
}
```

`What is the point of the price on the "seller"?` 
The sale is determined by the seller price, if buyer is priced higher, he will get refound.

This is a kind of simulation transfer of stock market. as under my understanding, if x buy at 200, y sell at 105, it will sell at 105, and x get 95 back.

Comment: What is the point of the `price` on the "seller"? Surely that means the "price they want to sell at" and therefore why should the listed buyers offers be applied when they do not meet that price? I think you're missing a lot of explanation of the core logic here. Also you have promises that don't return any value, and that's not a good thing. And just `return StockTransferPlatform.find({type: 'buyer', firmid: firmid, completed: false, withdraw: false})` No need for `.then()` which is only just returning the same value anyway.

Comment: @NeilLunn The sale value is determined by the sellers, not buyers in this case. (updated question). Thanks for claryfying the no need for .then()

Comment: That was actually my point. **Sell at 6** is what the "sellers" data is saying. You want to **Buy at 2** and **Buy at 5**. Both are **under** the seller price. Furthermore you are saying to give *preference* to the **lowest price** and not the **highest**, as would be expected. So either you have your explanation backwards or there is an error in the base logic of how you think this is solved. Really confusing and needs clarification or correction.

Comment: you are completly right @NeilLunn . there was a mess up. i believe its now sorted out correctly.